# "ls -t remotefile localfile" does not work over FTP

Tags: unix, ftp, ls

I'm interested in listing remote files (with names matching a pattern) by date, and storing this list locally. The various things I've tried follow:

---

```
ls -t SL*.txt
```

...is interpreted as a request to output to a local file named `SL*.txt`.

---

```
ls SL*.txt local_out.txt
```

...behaves correctly but without the desired sorting behavior.

---

```
ls -t SL*.txt local_out.txt
```

...results in an error:

```
usage: ls remote-directory local-file
```

---

How can I get a time-sorted remote directory list, filtered for only matching content, saved to a file?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: `-t` is not an available flag to the FTP ls command (which is _not_ the same as just running the shell ls command remotely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that `ls` command over ftp is somehow related to the shell `ls` command is incorrect: when you type `ls ...` into ftp window, the command gets interpreted by the ftp server on the other side, and it may not be even running UNIX, and know nothing about ls command and the switches that it supports. The `s remote-directory local-file` is the only syntax available; there is no place to enter switches.